# Can't play particular AVI files

Tags: raspbmc, video

My raspberry pi is playing most things from the network fine, but it won't play the following, no errors but just leaves me on the menu. I've done some research and it's h264 and only Main@L3.0.. so from what I've read it should work.. what have I missed?

First time posting so apologies if I've not provided all the info you need, let me know.

Here are the details

```
Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : H264
Duration                                 : 1h 44mn
Bit rate                                 : 839 Kbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 308 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.35:1
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.151
Stream size                              : 628 MiB (65%)
Writing library                          : x264 core
Color primaries                          : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : 2000
Duration                                 : 1h 44mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 448 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 335 MiB (35%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 32 ms (0.80 video frame)
```

I've got some logs, not much in the normal logs but with debug enabled the following looks interesting. I can provide more if useful.

```
08:43:06 T:2826957888   DEBUG: ffmpeg[A87FF440]: [h264] Current profile doesn't provide     more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
08:43:06 T:2826957888   DEBUG: ffmpeg[A87FF440]: [avi] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5024000
08:43:06 T:2826957888   DEBUG: ffmpeg[A87FF440]: [avi] decoding for stream 0 failed
```

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious, do you have other h264 files that play well? if you do, please, extract the same stats info and see if there's any difference. most probably you'll find the culprit or find the file with the same characteristics as this one, in which case this file might be just broken or slightly corrupted, that prevents the playback.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set your GPU and RAM splitting, without it it may not get all the needed ressources to successfully play back.

e.g. put this in your config.txt and reboot afterwards:

> gpu_mem_512=256

I'm assuming you have a model B with 512mb ram, otherwise use this:

> gpu_mem_256=128

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, no difference. I've checked other avi's made by the same tool (identical process) and they don't work either. I'll see if I can find other h264 files that do play and will post for the comparison. These files play fine on windows.